# How can I parse a diffgam.xml file with perl in a way to get array of hashes instead of a big hash-map?

Tags: arrays, xml, perl, hash

I get following diffgram XML from a service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xvcs:diffgram xmlns:xvcs="http://www.xvcs.org/">
  <xvcs:update id="7" first-child-of="/opt/node/node[1]">
    <xvcs:attr-update name="location" old-value="???" new-value="testlocation"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:update id="35" follows="/opt/node/node[2]">
    <xvcs:attr-update name="URL" old-value="/" new-value="/testurl/"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:insert id="75" first-child-of="/opt">
    <node node_id="/1234" location="new location" URL="/newurl"></node>
  </xvcs:insert>
</xvcs:diffgram>
```

I'm parsing it with XML::Simple in this way:

```
my $diffgram_hashref = XMLin($diffgram->toString(1),
                                KeepRoot    => 1,
                                ForceArray  => 1,
                        );

$logger->debug( dump($diffgram_hashref) );
```

and get following result:

```
{
  "xvcs:diffgram" => [
    {
      "xmlns:xvcs"  => "http://www.xvcs.org/",
      "xvcs:insert" => {
                         75 => {
                                 "first-child-of" => "/opt",
                                 "node" => [
                                   {
                                     node_id    => "/1234",
                                     location   => "new location",
                                     URL        => "/newurl",
                                   },
                                 ],
                               },
                       },
      "xvcs:update" => {
                         7  => {
                                 "first-child-of"   => "/opt/node/node[1]",
                                 "xvcs:attr-update" => {
                                                         location => { "new-value" => "testlocation", "old-value" => "???" },
                                                       },
                               },
                         35 => {
                                 "follows" => "/opt/node/node[2]",
                                 "xvcs:attr-update" => {
                                        URL => { "new-value" => "/testurl/", "old-value" => "/" },
                                 },
                               },
                       },
    },
  ],
}
```

I tried several ForeArray / KeyAttr combinations but I did not achieve to get the diffgram statements (update, insert) as array in order to proceed them in correct order:

```
{
  "xvcs:diffgram" => [
    {
      "xvcs:update" => {
                         7  => {
                                 "first-child-of"   => "/opt/node/node[1]",
                                 "xvcs:attr-update" => {
                                                         location => { "new-value" => "testlocation", "old-value" => "???" },
                                                       },
                               }
                        }
    },
    {
      "xvcs:update" => {
                         35 => {
                                 "follows" => "/opt/node/node[2]",
                                 "xvcs:attr-update" => {
                                        URL => { "new-value" => "/testurl/", "old-value" => "/" },
                                 },
                               },
                        }
    },
    {
      "xvcs:insert" => {
                         75 => {
                                 "first-child-of" => "/opt",
                                 "node" => [
                                   {
                                     node_id    => "/1234",
                                     location   => "new location",
                                     URL        => "/newurl",
                                   },
                                 ],
                               },
                       },
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: When you say you tried several combinations... what exactly did you try and what are you trying to accomplish? I would suggest that what you're trying is sufficiently un-simple that using XML:Twig instead of XML::Simple is the way forward.

Comment: I tried different combinations of ForceArray and KeyAttr like `my $diffgram_hashref = XMLin($diffgram->toString(1), KeepRoot => 1, ForceArray => ['xvcs:insert', 'xvcs:update'], KeyAttr => undef);`

or 

`my $diffgram_hashref = XMLin($diffgram->toString(1), KeepRoot => 1, ForceArray => ['xvcs:diffgram'], KeyAttr => undef);`

I will have a look at XML::Twig, thx for that hint

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish though? What is the expected output of your script? Do you want to work through each element in order?

Comment: The expected output should be an array of statements (update, insert) in the right order. Unfortunately the id is not continuous, so this is no identifier to sort.

Comment: If you showed the *“array of hashes*” that you would like from that data, I would happily write a script that used `XML::Twig` to create it for you.

Comment: @Borodin that's nice. I described the array of hashes above (last code-part)

Comment: What are you intending to do with your array of hashes? That's not a useful endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program does what you ask using the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) module. I've ignored the top-level hash key `xvcs:diffgram` as that hash has only a single element. The same applies to each hash within the array -- I would prefer to see the element tag as the value of one of the elements of the subsidiary hash, because as it stands you have an array of on-element hashes; however I have left this structure as you describe it.

I have also left the `id`, `name` and `URL` attributes as simple hash elements instead of treating them specially as your example does.

I have used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) only to show the structure that is built from the data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse(\*DATA);

my @data;

for my $node ( $twig->root->children ) {

  my $atts = $node->atts;

  for my $child ($node->children) {
    $atts->{$child->tag} = $child->atts;
  }

  push @data, { $node->tag => $atts };
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;



__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xvcs:diffgram xmlns:xvcs="http://www.xvcs.org/">
  <xvcs:update id="7" first-child-of="/opt/node/node[1]">
    <xvcs:attr-update name="location" old-value="???" new-value="testlocation"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:update id="35" follows="/opt/node/node[2]">
    <xvcs:attr-update name="URL" old-value="/" new-value="/testurl/"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:insert id="75" first-child-of="/opt">
    <node node_id="/1234" location="new location" URL="/newurl"></node>
  </xvcs:insert>
</xvcs:diffgram>
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "xvcs:update" => {
      "first-child-of" => "/opt/node/node[1]",
      "id" => 7,
      "xvcs:attr-update" => {
        "name" => "location",
        "new-value" => "testlocation",
        "old-value" => "???",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "xvcs:update" => {
      "follows" => "/opt/node/node[2]",
      "id" => 35,
      "xvcs:attr-update" => {
        "name" => "URL",
        "new-value" => "/testurl/",
        "old-value" => "/",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "xvcs:insert" => {
      "first-child-of" => "/opt",
      "id" => 75,
      "node" => {
        location => "new location",
        node_id => "/1234",
        URL => "/newurl",
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete solution based on comments so far. Hopefully it'll illustrate why Borodin and I are requesting what you're *actually* trying to get out of your parse.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new()->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $thing ( $twig->root->children() ) {
    print $thing ->tag, "\n";
    foreach my $att ( keys %{ $thing->atts() } ) {
        print "\t", $att, "=", $thing->att($att), "\n";
    }
    my $op = $thing->first_child;
    print "\t\t", $op->name, "\n";
    foreach my $att ( keys %{ $op->atts } ) {
        print "\t\t\t", $att, "=", $op->att($att), "\n";
    }

}

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xvcs:diffgram xmlns:xvcs="http://www.xvcs.org/">
  <xvcs:update id="7" first-child-of="/opt/node/node[1]">
     <xvcs:attr-update name="location" old-value="???" new-value="testlocation"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:update id="35" follows="/opt/node/node[2]">
    <xvcs:attr-update name="URL" old-value="/" new-value="/testurl/"/>
  </xvcs:update>
  <xvcs:insert id="75" first-child-of="/opt">
    <node node_id="/1234" location="new location" URL="/newurl"></node>
  </xvcs:insert>
</xvcs:diffgram>
```

This will print:

```
xvcs:update
    first-child-of=/opt/node/node[1]
    id=7
        xvcs:attr-update
            old-value=???
            new-value=testlocation
            name=location
xvcs:update
    follows=/opt/node/node[2]
    id=35
        xvcs:attr-update
            old-value=/
            new-value=/testurl/
            name=URL
xvcs:insert
    first-child-of=/opt
    id=75
        node
            URL=/newurl
            location=new location
            node_id=/1234
```

They key point being that turning your XML into an array of hashes is - probably - an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're focussing on trying to do something one way, and the answer is - probably - don't do it that way.

Comment: I didn't know that "XY problem" is called like this. Thanks for this link and your help